# Install artifact to a specific remote Maven repositories

Tags: maven, repository

I have an FTP where I would like to have my personal Maven repository, I would like my artifacts to be installed to that remote folder, how can achieve that?

Thanks,
Adam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use altDeploymentRepository configuration property of maven-deploy-plugin (see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html)).

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <altDeploymentRepository>your-repository-url</altDeploymentRepository>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Assuming I add this to my default parent pom, and all works fine from my machine. Next someone else which have access to my sources, on their own machine, installs the project, and they don't have the repository details in their settings.xml, do you have any idea what will happened?

Comment: He won't be able to deploy the project to your repository. He will still be able to build it locally with mvn install.